# Problem with useCallback not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I'm expecting that when I pass a function wrapped in `useCallback` as an attribute to another function, that the function will still work, but the function will not be re-created on each call.

I have this problem in a large application, but I've made the problem into a small, reproducible example that I can share here.

Below is the code that I'm struggling with. I have commented out my attempt at working with `useCallback` that is not working as expected.  When I don't use `useCallback` (the non-commented out code), the app toggles the theme as I expect.

I have the simple example in codesandbox at this URL:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pkellner/callback-theme-toggle

If I un-comment the `useCallback` line, the theme toggles once, then never toggles again.

My expectation is that with the `useCallback` code that the theme will toggle and appMenu.js will not get re-rendered on every theme toggle click.

Here is the `/pages/index.js`

```
import {useCallback, useContext} from "react";
import AppMenu from "../src/AppMenu";
import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from "../src/ThemeContext";

function Inner() {
  const { toggleTheme, darkTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
      {/*<AppMenu toggleTheme={useCallback(toggleTheme,[])} />*/}
      <AppMenu toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
      <h2>darkTheme: {darkTheme === true ? "true" : "false"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Inner />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
useCallback(toggleTheme,[])
```

This tells React that the value to use at that point is the value of `toggleTheme` *when the component mounts*. Since the dependency array is empty, the callback never changes.

When the component mounts, `toggleTheme` in context closes over the state value at that point:

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    console.log(`useTheme:toggleTheme:${darkTheme}`);
    setDarkTheme(!darkTheme); // <---- reference to state
};
```

`darkTheme` is `false` at that point. Although the value passed down by `useContext` changes when the component re-renders, because you're using `useCallback` with an empty dependency array, the value returned by `useCallback` remains the same - it refers to the initial `toggleTheme` from context, where `darkTheme` is its initial value (so further clicks don't appear to produce a change, because you're setting state to the same state as it is currently).

`useCallback` doesn't make any sense here; just use the value returned by `useContext` so that it always has the most up-to-date state value, instead of adding extra complication. The function is re-created by context, not by your use (or lack thereof) of `useCallback`.

If you want `AppMenu` to not re-render, then you should memoize it - and you should fix the context's `toggleTheme` so that the function it passes down doesn't depend on a reference to a (possibly stale) state value in the closure.

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
    setDarkTheme(theme => !theme);
};
```

```
function Inner() {
  const { toggleTheme, darkTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const menu = useMemo(() => <AppMenu toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
      {menu}
      <h2>darkTheme: {darkTheme === true ? "true" : "false"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer works if I add an empty dependency array as the 2nd param of useMemo. I'm still now following why useCallback will not work there as it seems we are memoizing a function and I thought that is what useCallback does.

Comment: The problem with using `useCallback` or `useMemo` is that memoizing it will memoize the *stale state value* - if you memoize it and it has the `setDarkTheme(!darkTheme);` line inside, you'll have integrated the `darkTheme` value from when the component mounted, so running the function will always result in only setting the theme in one direction, and never the other. Don't memoize the callback - memoize the AppMenu component instead, while making sure `toggleTheme` doesn't depend on an outer state value.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few points to address here.

When you `useCallback`, you create a closure around whatever dependencies it has. The callback needs to be recreated whenever one of those dependencies changes. The "meat" of your callback is this:

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
  setDarkTheme(!darkTheme);
};
```

Which means you have two dependencies - `setDarkTheme` (which is functionally stable), and `darkTheme` (which changes). So, when you wrap this in a `useCallback` and don't declare `darkTheme` as a dependency, the callback closures over the initial value of `darkTheme`, and always then uses that to toggle on (which is why the toggle works one time, but then never works again).

But good news! You can get rid of your dependency on `darkTheme` by using the callback version of `setState` -

```
const toggleTheme = () => {
  setDarkTheme(prev => !prev);
};
```

Boom! Now you have a functionally stable callback! You can safely wrap this into a `useCallback` hook with no dependencies, and it will work as you had intended!

But... you'll notice that even if you do that, `AppMenu` will *always* re-render when the them changes. Toggling the theme updates your `Context` object, and:

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.

([from the doco of `Context`)](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider).

`Inner` is a consumer of the context (via the `useContext` hook), and the parent of `AppMenu` - which means they both re-render when the context changes.

Comment: That’s very helpful.  I’m trying to create an example that uses useCallback to prevent a rerender (for a tutorial).  Do you see a way to restructure( while still with useCallback) the keeps the menu from rerendering?

Comment: If the menu is rendered inside a Context, the only option would be to memoize the menu - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: I’m having so much trouble coming up with a useCallback example.

Comment: Unless you have a really good use case, you probably _shouldn't_ `useCallback` (or `useMemo`). Kent Dodds has a really good article explaining why (long, but worth the read) - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Thanks.  I have read that article several times.  Kent points out that his example of a good use of useCallback is contrived.  I’m struggling to find a non contrived good use.

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usecallback/#3-a-good-use-case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248776/discussion-between-gerrod-and-peter-kellner).